# How to toggleClass from list items to display:none, display:block

Tags: jquery, html, css

When the screen is size is smaller than 800px I will show this: `<a class='expand' href='#'>. . .</a>`  after the first list element.
The aim is when the . . . are clicked I want to show all the other items in the list. I tried to use the toggle() method from jQuery, but it shows a list like this:
->

- item1
- item2
- item3

I want to toggle the class of the list items who come after the first list item between display: none and diplay: inline-block. But it doesn't work right now.

But I want to show the list items in an inline-block.

I append the anchor tag to the first element of the list. Here is the code when the anchor tag is clicked.

```js
$(".breadcumb .expand").on("click", function() {
  $("breadcumb li").toggleClass('.show');
});

$(".breadcumb li:first-child").append("<a class='expand' href='#'>. . .</a>");
```

```css
.breadcumb li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.expand {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block;
}

.breadcumb li:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* When the screen width is < 800, do the following */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .expand {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  div.uc_breadcrumb_block .breadcumb li:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none;
  }
  div.uc_breadcrumb_block .breadcumb li:first-child {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="uc_breadcrumb_block">
    <ul class="breadcumb">
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
      <li>item5</li>
      <li>item6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".breadcumb li:first-child").append("<a class='expand' href='#'>. . .</a>");

$(".breadcumb .expand").on("click", function(){
    $(".breadcumb li").toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.breadcumb li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.expand {
  display: none;
}

.breadcumb li.show{
  display: inline-block;
}


/* When the screen width is < 800, do the following */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.breadcumb li{
  display: none;
}
  .expand{
    display: inline-block;
  }

  div.uc_breadcrumb_block .breadcumb li:first-child {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <div class="uc_breadcrumb_block">
      <ul class="breadcumb">
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
        <li>item6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the solution. Hope it helps

Updated the code now it will work only below 800px screen size

Comment: I tested it out and it worked, but how can I get it to work when the list elements are also visible when the screen is > 800px. When the screen is > 800px I want to show everything and I don't want to hide all the list elements. When the screen is < 800px I only want to show the first element unless the . . . is clicked.

Comment: so you want this behavior below 800px screen?

Comment: updated the code just by default your li needs to be inline-block and below 800px it needs to be display:none

Answer (score 1):

you can use **:not(:first-child)** selector to select all child other than first child

```js
$(".breadcrumb li:first-child").append("<a class='expand' href='#'>. . .</a>");

$(document).on("click",".breadcrumb .expand", function() {
  $(".breadcrumb li").not(":first-child").toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.breadcrumb li {
  display: none;
}
.breadcrumb li:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
.breadcrumb li.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="uc_breadcrumb_block">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
      <li>item5</li>
      <li>item6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with the :not operator is that it is not supported by all browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot

Comment: instead of ":not "selector you can use ".not()" function  of js ...it has browser support..i have modified my answer check it